# getBoundingBoxSize crashing sometimes

Tags: swift, crash, scenekit, exc-bad-access

I have a strange problem with using `getBoundingBoxSize` on `SCNText` geometry - it sometimes causes a crash - `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1)`. Can't figure out why. I use it on main thread.

[image]

This happens on iOS 12. Can someone help me resolve this?

```
        let node = node as! AugmentedRealityView3DObjectNode
        let mediaNode = mediaNode as! SCNNode
        let fontScalling:   Float = 0.5 
        let marginScalling: Float = 0.9 
        let planeGeometry = mediaNode.geometry as! SCNPlane
        let textNode = mediaNode.childNodes.first!
        let mediaTextGeometry = textNode.geometry as! SCNText
        mediaTextGeometry.containerFrame = CGRect(withSize: CGSize(fromSize3D: node.augmentedRealityView.sizeForMainNode(node: node)) / CGFloat(fontScalling * marginScalling), centeredInContainerOfSize: .zero)
        let centerPoint = SCNVector3(getBoundingCenterPoint: mediaTextGeometry.boundingBox)
        textNode.position = SCNVector3(-centerPoint.x, -centerPoint.y, -centerPoint.z) * fontScalling * marginScalling
        textNode.scale = SCNVector3(qubicVector: fontScalling * marginScalling)
        // TODO: This causes crashes sometines in iOS 12.
        let boundingBoxSize = SCNVector3(getBoundingBoxSize: mediaTextGeometry.boundingBox) * fontScalling / marginScalling
        planeGeometry.width = CGFloat(boundingBoxSize.x)
        planeGeometry.height = CGFloat(boundingBoxSize.y)
```

Comment: Never put a screenshot in here—always provide code in text form.

Comment: This code is actually not very important here, I wanted to show also functions executed in the left side. I will add the code anyway, thanks

Comment: Check that in which variable you are getting crash.

Comment: Crash is from reading mediaTextGeometry.boundingBox. It crashes even if I just print it

Answer (score 1):

This is still broken 2.5 years later in SceneKit in iOS 14.2. The best I can tell, you cannot invoke .boundingBox on a node with SCNText geometry until after the node has been rendered at least once. My guess is that something is not initialized until the render loop and boundingBox fails to check for it being uninitialized.

My workaround is the usual hack of putting the .boundingBox in a DispatchQueue.main.asyc {} block so (hopefully) the node & geometry have been initialized. Depending on your app, this may not be feasible.

Comment: We are also experiencing this same crash. Has anyone filed a radar bug report with Apple?

Comment: I filed FB8904263 last November.

Answer (score 0):

You are crashing in the Objective-C memory management system, which usually indicates some kind of heap corruption. I would guess that some object has been prematurely deallocated, while references to it still exist. This is super common, and is often called a dangling pointer.

I'd suggest checking out the Zombies tool in Instruments. It can help find this kinds of errors. Good luck!